# How to request geolocation in CLLocationManager with `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, cllocation, ios13

It seems like the user can not get the `Always Allow` option when the app request geolocation in CLLocationManager with `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in iOS 13. 
It shows `Allow While Using App` and `Allow Once` instead.

Environment: iOS 13 beta 6, Xcode beta 5, iPhone X

[image]

How can I prompt `Always Allow` to users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works correct. If user will press the best positive answer in that case which is `Allow While Using App` the operating system will remember that.System will present user alert at some point of time when some special event occurs. System will present alert with `Keep Only While Using` and `Change to Always Allow` options.
For more information you can check on video from WWDC 2019 [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/) from 2:40.

Comment: Very nice answer. I saw the explanation on WWDC as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include a description of all these keys in the `info.plist`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these in the page which needs user location.

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```